# AngularJS BootstrapUI Typeahead add new element if not match

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to configure bootstrap typeahead to add new elements if the text doesn't match with data array.

I use angular-boostrap typeahead 0.13.0 with angular 1.3.16.

I'm not able to do the typeahead takes my query string as an argument tu push.

My data y an object of id and name, if a new item is added, id is set to null.

Comment: you can use ``typeahead-focus-first="false"``  do just use the query string and not automatically select on in the typeahead array!

Comment: If the item appear ng-mode variable contains the item object and if not appears contain the same object with the input string but id is set to null